# Is there an function that get array of numbers and return ranges?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I hope that, I'm explaining myself right.
I need to write a function that gets an array of numbers and returns an array of ranges if there is.

For example:

**`[1,2,3,5,6,8,9,10]` -----> `[[1,2,3],[5,6],[8,9,10]]`**

Comment: Show what you have tried so far, explain how it fails and we might be able to help.

Comment: It's not clear how the function will return ranges

Comment: is the data ordered, as it looks like?

Comment: hey Michal, there is no such built-in function. Please show us if you tried anything and we can help you from there.

Comment: What's the correlation between your input and expected output?

Comment: _“I hope that I'm explaining myself right.”_ - by _just_ explaining what you “need”, you are not even _asking_ right to begin with. This site is not a research service or a code-writing service; we want you to show us what you already tried to solve the problem yourself first of all. Please go read [ask].

Comment: thank you for trying to help me!! but i got my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the previous value and insert a new array, if the delta is not one.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10],
    result = array.reduce((r, v, i, { [i - 1]: p }) => {
        if (p === v - 1) r[r.length - 1].push(v);
        else r.push([v]);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```